# How can I publish a node-express website under an existing server?

Tags: node.js, express, server

I have a web-server with cPanel, but I didn't find the method to make the website properly work. I made an aldomain, updloaded the project, but it doesn't recognise the base css, nodejs server etc... Tha main question is how to run my own server.js file on the server(?!), and how to make it looks like on localhost? Is it possible? If it's not, how can I publish it? I know that I shouldn't send this message here, because it doesn't contain any code, but nobody tells me where can I ask theese kind of questions. Can you tell me this too, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad news is cPanel doesn't support Node.js. [Prof link](https://features.cpanel.net/topic/nodejs-hosting#comment-52316)

Good news is here you can make question without any code.

Comment: It's really bad news, but thank you for the decent answer :/